# How to save csv columns as variables?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

Sorry if this is an obvious answer, but I'm new to python coming from matlab. I'm trying to extract the columns from a csv file and save them as variables. It is a csv file with the first row as headers (depth, salinity, and pressure) and the remaining rows are numbers. I want the columns not including the first row. This is my code so far but it's giving me a triangular matrix.

`

```
#Import your CTD data files 
salinity1=[]
depth1=[]
temperature1=[]
ctd1row=[]
#importing ctd 1
import csv
with open('ctd11.csv') as file:
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        ctd1row.append(row);
    for column in ctd1row:
        depth1.append(column[1])
        print(depth1)
```

`

Comment: _This is my code so far but it's giving me a triangular matrix_ I have no idea what a "triangular matrix" is.  Show us the _actual output_ of the code, and explain how it's different from what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use this as a sample .csv:

| depth | salinity | pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25.3 | 25 |
| 11 | 45 | 20.7 |

There's a few approaches you can take.

The csv reader reads row by row, so one option would be:

Read the header and make a "translator" (`idx_to_colname` in the code below) of which index corresponds with which column name and [another dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep the actual values, where the keys are the column names and the values are a list. Then you keep reading the next rows (as lists), and say *"Oh, ok... index `[1]` corresponds with the column "salinity", so when I read a row, I will store its index `[1]` into the `contents["salinity"]` list"*

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

contents = defaultdict(list)
idx_to_colname = {}
with open('SO-74201357.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(reader)
    for index, colname in enumerate(header):
        idx_to_colname[index] = colname
    for row in reader:
        for index, value in enumerate(row):
            contents[idx_to_colname[index]].append(value)
print(contents)
print(f"salinity: {contents['salinity']}")

# Outputs:
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'depth': ['10', '11'], 'salinity': ['25.3', '45'], 'pressure': ['25', '20.7']})
# salinity: ['25.3', '45']
```

A second option, maybe slower, but that will make the code more readable is using the ability of the `csv` module to give you dictionaries on the shape `{col_1_name: val...}`. It will look at the column names on the first row and match them with the values on each row. See the [DictReader class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) in the csv module.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

contents = defaultdict(list)
with open('SO-74201357.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        for key, val in row.items():
            contents[key].append(val)
print(contents)
print(f"salinity: {contents['salinity']}")

# Outputs:
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'depth': ['10', '11'], 'salinity': ['25.3', '45'], 'pressure': ['25', '20.7']})
# salinity: ['25.3', '45']
```

A third option, and that might interest you in the longer term is installing the very complete [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) package and [read the .csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) file into a DataFrame (sort of like a matrix where columns are easily referentiable by name):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('SO-74201357.csv')
print(f"Full:")
print(df)
print(f"Only 'salinity' column:")
print(df['salinity'])
# Outputs:
# Full:
#    depth  salinity  pressure
# 0     10      25.3      25.0
# 1     11      45.0      20.7
# Only 'salinity' column:
# 0    25.3
# 1    45.0
# Name: salinity, dtype: float64
```

I mention that it might interest you in the longer term because it comes with a myriad of tools to manipulate the data, filter it, merge it, transform it...